# Calculate value in keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a question about keypress in input. 
I have two inputs and this inputs must do division calculations. Today it works as follows independent of which input the user chooses to start typing it does the calculation via keypress. What i want to know is if there is a better or more performative way of doing this.

```
<input id="inputone" type="text" />
<input id="inputtwo" type="text" />
$('#inputone').keypress(function() {
    let inputOne = $('#inputone').val();
    let inputTwo = $('#inputtwo').val();
    if (inputTwo) {
      let calculate = parseFloat(inputOne/inputTwo);
      alert(calculate);
     }
 });

$('#inputtwo').keypress(function() {
  let inputOne = $('#inputone').val();
  let inputTwo = $('#inputtwo').val();
  if (inputOne) {
    let calculate = parseFloat(inputOne/inputTwo);
    alert(calculate);
  }
 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1az8cwkf/16/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#inputone, #inputtwo').on('change keyup input', (function() {

  $('label').html(
    $('#inputone').val() && $('#inputtwo').val() ?
    $('#inputone').val() / $('#inputtwo').val() : '0')
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputone" type="number"> /
<input id="inputtwo" type="number"> =
<label>0</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the blur function would be a good idea incase someone was trying to type `1400` it wouldn't keep dividing every time they clicked a key. Instead it will divide when they click out.

```
$('#inputone').blur(function() {

$('#inputtwo').blur(function() {
```

Or you could make a divide button to do it once a user wants to divide.

```
<input id="divideButton" type="button" />
```

with:

```
$('#divideButton').click(function() {
```

Comment: I think UX implications are costly. As a user, I'd like to get the result as fast as possible, with fewest number of taps and clicks (especially clicks) possible. Although as one of the solutions of performance problem, it could work, I must agree.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is performant enough. Yes, jQuery is slower than native DOM API; yes, the code might have been refactored to remove syntactic duplication. Yet there's one thing that I think could be added to improve it: *callback throttling.*

If the user is typing too fast, they will see the changes perhaps too quickly to even comprehend it, at the expense of browser performance, especially if the calculation becomes huge. To ease the load, you could use [lodash's `_.throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle) or [`_.debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) functions, or implement your own higher-order function that would prevent the callback to be executed too often.

So it could look like

```
calculate = _.debounce(() => {
  const inputOne = $('#inputone').val();
  const inputTwo = $('#inputtwo').val();

  if (inputOne !== '' && inputTwo !== '') {
    const result = parseFloat(inputOne / inputTwo);
    alert(result);
  }
}, 300);

$('#inputone').keypress(calculate);
$('#inputtwo').keypress(calculate);
```

Make sure lodash library (or your own function) is loaded and available in global scope (or imported, if you use modules).

In fact, lodash is quite a large lib that will eat a good part of your performance budget, so make sure you really have a performance problem that is critical to be solved.

Comment: The line `parseFloat(inputOne / inputTwo)` will break. You can't divide a string by another string; you have to parse each string as a number first, then divide those numbers.

Comment: Nope, it won’t. Please try it first.

Comment: That's peculiar... Does JavaScript automatically parse the strings as numbers during the division? I'm intrigued at how that works now.